# Can we pass null to laravel resource

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I have InitResource that return basic data like some app data like app name etc..

Now if user is logged in, I return resource with user data or without user data, but when the user is null or `auth()->user()` is null, I get some error:

> Cant return id of null

```
public function __get($key)
{
    return $this->resource->{$key};
}
```

And when user is logged it works like it should.
Logically I am trying to return resource without data, but can I use it with some "default values" ?

In resource I am checking:

```
$data = [
    'appName' => config('app.name'),
    'locale' => app()->getLocale(),
];

if($this->hasRole('basic')) {
    $data['user'] = $this->only(['username', 'fullname', 'avatar']);
}


return $data;
```

Can this be done in resource? With passed null? Thanks

Comment: You should check before return whether resource id is null or not. return $this->resource->{$key} ?? null

Comment: You can set default value like `__get($key = 'your value')` **OR** You should validate the key as @AbdurRahman mentioned above

Comment: Probably the method hasRole access the user and try to get the roles id / slug from it, but if it isn't logged, it returns null. I see you trying to make a user/role/permission, I suggest you to use [https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-roles].

Comment: @AbdurRahman I returned array with default data in controller and called user resource if user is logged.

Comment: @RafaelQm Whats different with that package? I am simply using roles table pivot and users. It works fine.. Any explanation why do you suggest that package?

Comment: @Learner You can define what role can do, like, certain role can show users, but cannot edit, you can put this rules on database, letting the user to configura, besides, is a well documented, so if you project you need to put more developers, is more easy to them get the rules.

Comment: Oh okay, nice thing. I dont need I am making website to work alone, roles are between users like students and teachers, students have like schools page and teachers have applied students page. I use roles just to send api check is that student or teacher on accessible page. But ill save link for research